# Why did the support for mapping type removed from ES 6.x?

Tags: elasticsearch

What happens to our existing mapping types when we upgrade ? Is there any direct upgrade option?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple types in one index your mapping will not work for all of them because in 6.x in one index there is just one mappings type.

> If you have just one type in one index then there will be no issue with your mappings.

[Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking why elasticsearch removed the support for mapping, this [post](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html) explains it. 
Now to you question on existing mapping types, for indices created in version 5 with multiple mapping types, they will work fine after the upgrade to 6, however new indices created in 6 can have only one type. So if you application is reading from indices created in 5 and 6 together, then you may have an issue.